# Easy way to stack vectors of vectors in Julia

Tags: vector, julia

I would like a way to programmatically "deconstruct" a vector of variable-length vectors in Julia. I do not care about the resulting vector's order.

For example, suppose that my vector of vectors is `A = [[1], [2,3], [4,5,6]]`. I can deconstruct `A` by writing `vcat(A[1], A[2], A[3])`, which returns `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. However, if the length of `A` is large, then this approach becomes cumbersome. Is there a better, more scalable way to obtain the same result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I would second Przemyslaw's answer for any situation where you can get away with using a lazy representation, maybe a more direct answer to your question is:

```
julia> vcat(A...)
6-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

whenever you feel the need to type out all elements of a collection as function arguments, splatting `...` is your friend.

Splatting can however negatively impact performance, so it is generally recommended to use `reduce`, which has a specialisation for `vcat`:

```
julia> reduce(vcat, A)
6-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

Answer (score 7):

Try `Iterators.flatten`:

```
julia> collect(Iterators.flatten(A))
6-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

(This yields a lazy representation hence I `collect`ed this before showing the output)